# 19.04 gnome session login after blank screen - is it impossible without mouse?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, login, gdm

Since 19.04, there seems to be a **problem logging into to a gnome session** using the keyboard only, after returning from a blank screen. None of the fields will have focus.

*What I want:* **using the keyboard only** for

1. selecting a user from the gdm3 selection list
2. entering the password

and minding my business.

Once I seemed to be able to `<tab>` through the user names, but that supposedly was after a mouse move or touching the name list at least.

I *think* I tried almost every combo of keystrokes that seem intuitive to achieve the described goal.

So: is there a key combination to get the user select list back in focus?

Comment: just down scrolling is making me to choose user and then enter.. cant reproduce the issue..

Comment: Up/Down arrow keys to select user, ENTER key to select, enter password.

Comment: great. now it works.
I wonder what you did.

thanks ;)

Comment: @heynnema Post that as an answer? :)

Comment: and how do I **access the menu** (top right) just using the **keyboard**?

Comment: **HAH!** the problem resurfaced.

I _can't log in without mouse_ when **returning from blank screen & lock**

Comment: This is fixed in 19.10. Just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

To use only keyboard entry at the login screen:

```
- selecting a user from the gdm3 selection list
- entering the password
```

<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys to select desired user, <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key to select user, enter the password, <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key to log in.

Comment: _can't log in without mouse_ when **returning from blank screen & lock**