# 19.04 gnome-session login after screen blank -- impossible without mouse

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, login-screen, gdm

as posted before ([19.04 gnome session login - is it impossible without mouse?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1150766/846139))
this seems to be the case.

apart from that, I'd like to know how to **get the top-right 
settings/shutdown menu** just by using the **keyboard**.

thanks

Comment: I haaatee Steam for forcing me to use a mouse for its start offline mode... Windows or Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 0):

try to keep the two questions separate.

anyhow, for the last question, see my solution here for a similar scenario
[19.04 gnome-session login after screen blank -- impossible without mouse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159382/19-04-gnome-session-login-after-screen-blank-impossible-without-mouse)

and if you dont have the showallwindows tweak, those coordinates should get you to the top right of the screen, and then do a mouseclick, using your designated keyboard shortcut. then it would be down arrows to your username, right arrow and enter logout

another one would a shortcut for

```
shutdown now
```

"shutdown may be used to halt, power-off or reboot the machine" That might require a sudo though.

or simply bring up the terminal with it's shortcut key and type it in.