# log in without mouse when returning after logout

Tags: keyboard, login-screen

I would like to be able to get to login screen using keyboard only. When rebooting there is no problem, but after logout (and maybe screen lock and suspend) it seems to be necessary to drag up the screen with the mouse. Is there a way to do it mouse-free? Similar questions were posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150766/19-04-gnome-session-login-after-blank-screen-is-it-impossible-without-mouse) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159382/19-04-gnome-session-login-after-screen-blank-impossible-without-mouse?answertab=votes#tab-top) but there is no solution there, at least not for the current Ubuntu (19.10)
Update: at the moment the problem solved itself, logging out brings me to the login screen, and not as before to a blank irresponsive to keyboard background screen. But I hate it when it happens and hope for a solution.

Comment: I thought you could use <ENTER>, but I switched to using `sddm` (instead of `gdm3`) so maybe it was that change that made it better for me.

Comment: Since this would be a very sensible thing to do, I'm 100% certain, that the gnome development team would not implement this, as it is against their design philosophy of creating software that works only for them.

Answer (score 2):

Just pressing any key works on my system running Ubuntu 19.10. You can even simply start typing the password directly at the lock screen. Pressing the first letter of the password on the lock screen shows the login screen with the first letter already registered.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the issue but it is inconsistent, at the moment your solution works for me, but sometimes I just get my smiling ermine background image, similar to after super+L, but I can't use any key to nudge it, only mouse. 
I am waiting to see if others have a solution for this state